# Laravel mix appropriate loader needed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

When I compile my assets

```
import './bootstrap';

import './components';

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

this is my package.json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "hot": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": 
  {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.4.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.4"
  }
}
```

Case.vue

```
<template>


    <div>
        <ul class="collection">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


</template>

<script>

</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

I thought laravel mix already took care the webpack configuration. This error, I remember deals with style-loader in webpack. But why it exists in laravle-mix

Comment: Do you have the error in full?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this script in your **index.blade.php**

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

With this you can compiled your assets in your laravel-Mix

hope this is the solution for your problem.